# TTURLRequest and sending POST data

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

I'm three20 for first time on an iOS app, and I'm stuck on something I can find more information.

I'm trying to send some POST data to my local server, but everytime I got a response : Error. If I try with GET parameters I have no problem.

The code I'm using is this :

```
TTURLRequest *request =
    [TTURLRequest requestWithURL:@"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login" delegate:self];

    request.cachePolicy = cachePolicy;
    request.response = [[[TTURLDataResponse alloc] init] autorelease];
    request.httpMethod = @"POST";

    NSString *myRequestString = @"username=######@gmail.com&password=66Ed############fxij";
    NSData *myRequestData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: [ myRequestString UTF8String ] length: [ myRequestString length ] ];
    request.contentType=@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    [request.parameters addObject:@"username" forKey:@"######@gmail.com"];
    [request.parameters addObject:@"password" forKey:@"6Ed############fxij"];
    request.httpBody = myRequestData;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but you do use a lot of code for the params. When I POST with TTURLRequests I usually just do:[request.parameters setObject:@"blah" forKey:@"username"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the params backwards too! That could be it. It should be:

```
[request.parameter addObject:@"####@gmail.com" forKey:@"username"];
```

Comment: Comment by [dmrutgos](http://stackoverflow.com/users/764321/) (rejected edit): Minor change, but the correct method for `NSMutableDictionary` is `setObject`, not `addObject`.